# insert Query throwing error

Tags: mysql

I am ran into a weird problem this particular query is not working

```
insert into `timesheet` 
    (`type`,`app_id`,`app_name`,`app_title`,
     `app_path`,`timestamp_start`,`timestamp_end`,`duration`,
     `user_id`,`matter_id`,`updated_by_user_id`,`timestamp_create`,
     `source`,`user_rate`,`cost`,`description`,
     `location_name`,`conflict`,`suggestion`) 
Values 
    ('PLUGIN', '5232', 'oMgqTrYiZVQp.exe', 'qZXhgWtnwvQq',
     'k', '2016-05-06T18:21:29.000Z', '2016-05-18 19:29:50.000', '1021101',
     '4', '1', '-1', '2019-06-15T01:13:34.000Z',
     NULL, '15000', '4254.5875', NULL,
     NULL, '0', NULL)
```

WHat I was doing is running man this query with different values, rest are working fine, but for this particular query, it throws the error.

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Can you pelase let me know what I am doing wrong or any hint would be appreciated so that i can debug it

Comment: Hi guys. There was some issue in the table triggers and because of a if statement, it failed. Is there anyway to figure out where the error originated in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you that the amount of columns you said you'd fill does not match the amount of columns you actually are giving data for. Make sure the amount of columns specified after *timesheet* matches the amount of columns filled after *Values*.

Additionally you may want to check if the source, description, location_name and suggestion columns allow NULLS. You can also test if it works if you replace the NULL values with dummy values (like an empty string or a 0).